# return other indexed fields using SearchApiQuery($index)

Tags: 7, search

I created an index that indexes taxonomy terms.
I indexed the term name + field_skill type text.
The current result shows only the term id + score.

I want to show also the field_skill.

```
 $term = 'drupal';

 // Select an index.
 $index = search_api_index_load("terms");
 $query = new SearchApiQuery($index);


 // Conditions.
 $query->condition('name', $term, '=');
 // $query->condition('language', $language->language, '=');

 // Fetch results.
 $results = $query->execute()['results'];
 dpm($results); // returns only ids and score I want to return other indexed fields
```

Comment: Which backend are you using? Solr? Db? Other?

Comment: Apache Solr Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Solr, on server configuration (admin/config/search/search_api/server/YOUR_SERVER_NAME/edit), under "Advanced" fieldset, you should enable the "Retrieve result data from Solr" option:

[image]